# Model HTTP POST with URL query parameters in swagger 2.0

Tags: rest, swagger

Newbie question: I have to rebuilt an old REST API, with some clients in Swagger 2.0. Unfortunatly some of the API calls use for HTTP post the following way: For the content it uses the POST body, but for a "sitekey" it use an URL Parameter.
so each post looks something like that:

```
POST api/update?sitekey=xxx  HTTP/1.1
....
{"json": "content"}
```

I must not ignore the sitekey, so how would i model such a thing in swagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jax-rs, you can use swagger's `@ApiParam` annotation. Depending on the jax-rs annotation (`@QueryParam`, `@PathParam`, etc.) used along with this annotation, swagger will identify the parameter placement correctly. See here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apiparam